# How to force UIImagePickerController to record video in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, video-capture

I my application is running potrate mode but I want to record video in landscape mode.

```
    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imgPicker.editing=FALSE;
        //self.imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
        self.imgPicker.delegate = (id)self;

        [self.imgPicker shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
        //self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    #if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)    
        self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    #endif
imgPicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            NSArray *mediaTypesAllowed = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.movie"];
            [imgPicker setMediaTypes:mediaTypesAllowed];
            [self.imgPicker shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
            [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
```

I want to load `UIImagePickerController` in landscape mode by default.

Please guide me how to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

As Apple doc stated, UIImagePickerController (will be refered as UIIPC from now on) only works in portrait mode.  Your app will be rejeced. Anyway you can try this [url](http://www.mediafire.com/?ubc0i69jq4x8ex6) which opens in landscape mode.